# In Entity Framework database-first approach how to return multiple result sets from a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am working with Entity Framework using the database-first approach. I created a stored procedure in MySQL that returns multiple sets, I want to get all result sets on a single hit not only the top one result set.

In my stored procedure I am passing arguments too.

Comment: I am using Both Mysql and Sql . its must be run on both.I know in mysql i have to update my ssdl file through edmx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLQuery to execute your procedure:

```
public partial class NorthwindContext 
{
    public IEnumerable<CustomerOrderHistory> CustomerOrderHistory(string customerID)
    {
        var customerIDParameter = customerID != null ?
            new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", customerID) :
            new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", typeof(string));

        return Database.SqlQuery<CustomerOrderHistory>("CustOrderHist @CustomerID", customerIDParameter);
    }
}
```

and the model looks like:

```
public partial class CustomerOrderHistory
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Total { get; set; }
}
```

It's sample based on Northwind Database

Comment: This does not address multiple recordset as OP asked in question.

Comment: Is it mean return different list of objects? or return list of custom object?

Comment: I think OP is having two select statement in the stored procedure.

Comment: But needs to map with object, your solution is not using EF, and I know that can not use EF if wants to map to different entities

Comment: i did face this problem before, after researching i use ado.net return dataset for alternative.

Comment: I am using Both Mysql and Sql . its must be run on both.I know in mysql i have to update my ssdl file through edmx

Comment: So, I guess you can not use EF, it's better using traditional ADO.NET or change your procedure

Comment: its not possible because its client requirement I have too use database only through EF not on page And DB also not fixed it may be sql or mysql.It depend when we login

Comment: But if you want to use the EF you have to map to specific object. Can you do that?

Comment: I m very new in EF so i don't have too much idea so can u please provide some example.

Comment: @Peyman Why do you think my answer does not contains solution with EF. Solution make a use of `IObjectContextAdapter` & `ObjectContext` and also I believe EF is an ORM and you will get records in object when you call `Translate`.

Comment: @Jenish Rabadiya, what's advantage of using your solution with traditional ADO.NET? Of course you can use it with EF DataContext Connection, but there is not point to use this way. If suppose to use your solution, I prefer using ADO.NET

Answer (score 0):

use basic reader and make use of `reader.NextResult` method.

```
var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand(); 
cmd.CommandText = "some command here"; 

try 
{ 

    db.Database.Connection.Open();   
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
    var books = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db) 
        .ObjectContext 
        .Translate<Book>(reader, "Books", MergeOption.AppendOnly);    

    // Move to second result set and read authors
    reader.NextResult(); 
    var authors = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db) 
        .ObjectContext 
        .Translate<Author>(reader, "Authors", MergeOption.AppendOnly); 
} 
finally 
{ 
    db.Database.Connection.Close(); 
}
```